What does はね mean

私の夢はね誰かに抱きしめてもらう事だったんだ

I knows this sentence translates into "My dream was for someone to hug me". What I'm confused about is the はね part. As far as I understand, は is the topic marking particle, and ね is a sentence ender meant to signify shared information. So what is it doing right after the topic marking particle.
For context, the original quote was separated into two speech bubbles. The first bubble was 私の夢はね・・・ , and the second bubble was 誰かに抱きしめてもらう事だったんだ.

It's a filler particle. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34036/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78058/5010

Rather than "signifying shared information", I would characterize ね generally as "agreement-seeking". (After all, it's often attached to questions.) Or perhaps [相]{あい}づち-seeking is more like it. In colloquial speech, it has the same sort of phatic effect as "like" or "you know" in English.
Here, the speaker has split the utterance into two parts; the idea is to ensure that the listener resonates with the idea of 私の夢は as a topic before bothering to explain what that 夢 consists of. (Or also, perhaps, just to fill space while thinking about how to word it, without sounding unconfident like with ええと etc.)
