# Can sentence-ending particles be used at the end of an independent clause?

Tags: grammar, particles, sentence-final-particles

With the sentence:

> 「僕は今度遠い所へ行くから**ね**、その前一寸お前に遭いに来たよ。」

"I am leaving now to go to a far away place, so before that I came to meet you for a short time."

Assuming I read that right, then it seems like the **ね** is a sentence-ending particle sitting at the end of the 1st clause in this compound sentence ("I am leaving now to go to a far away place").

So that leads me to two questions:

1. **Can sentence-ending particles (よ, ね, な, etc) be used at the end of independent clauses in a compound sentence?**
2. **If this ね isn't the "seek agreement" particle, then what is it? An interjection?**

Comment: Related, maybe? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34036/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56270/9831

Comment: Possibly. But as I understand it, ね is a feminine "filler word" and since this is a male speaking, it seems unlikely that he'd be using it. (He hasn't used any feminine language before)

Comment: Men also use ね. Probably, it means ①3. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/169590/meaning/m0u/ね

Comment: Which seems the same as #2 from http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AD. That's what I had in mind when I mentioned "an interjection". It seems likely that's what it is, but I'd still like to get an answer to the grammar question of "Can the sentence-ending particles be used to end an independent clause as well as a sentence?"

Comment: No, this ね isn't the same as #2 from a dictionary you referred to.

Comment: The standard theory doesn't consider it a sentence ending particle, while some do, (which I personally find pointless because there's distinct difference in usage and meaning).

Answer (score 2):

> Can sentence-ending particles (よ, ね, な, etc) be used at the end of independent clauses in a compound sentence?

ね is different from other sentence particles in that it has no restrictions on the forms it can follow. See page 4 of [Japanese the Spoken Language Part 2](https://yalebooks.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Media/9780300041880_Jorden_Japanese%20Spoken%20Language%20Part%202/9780300041880_Lesson%2013.pdf).

> If this ね isn't the "seek agreement" particle, then what is it? An interjection?

As mentioned in chapter 10 of Japanese: The Spoken Language Part 1, a sentence is frequently broken up into shorter spans, with ね (often ね？or ね！ or even ねぇ) added to the nonfinal sentences. These uses of ね are meant to indicate the speaker's request for [あいづち](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%B8%E6%A7%8C), i.e. a confirmation from the listener that they are paying attention and are involved in the conversation, in the form of at least a firm nod, but often a verbalization like はい or ええ or even a form of そう.

Comment: Can I then assume that the other sentence particles (よ, な, ぞ, etc) **cannot** be used at the end of independent clauses? And as a side question, can な _also_ be used without restrictions like ね?

Comment: I had a feeling you'd ask that. In the English sense, an *independent clause* is a sentence, so naturally, they can be used. However, ね can follow *anything*, including *dependent clauses* (as in your example after から) or even single nominals. Other sentence particles normally *cannot*. When か follows something it actually creates a sentence (possibly a minor one, as in the case with imbedded questions). な is related to ね but I think it belongs only at the end of independent clauses (including following か). さ is a filler word so I think it can follow anything, like ね. Learn it case-by-case.

Comment: To clarify, here から ends a minor sentence, not a major sentence. Sentence particles generally end major sentences.